# Download file from URL up to x bytes in React Native (without react-native-fetch-blob)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to download a file in React Native with the restriction that only a max of x bytes will be downloaded.
This would be possible using react-native-fetch-blob which allows file streams but in my specific case it happens that I can't use react-native-fetch-blob. I'm looking for alternatives (preferably without any third-party library, but not a requirement)

In web javascript I could do this:

```js
async function download(url, maxBytes) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
    
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
    
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        let bytesRead = 0;
        let chunks = [];
        while (bytesRead < maxBytes) {
          const { done, value } = await reader.read();
          if (done) { break; }
          chunks.push(value);
          bytesRead += value.length;
        }
        reader.cancel("Download size limit reached.");
    
        const result = new Uint8Array(bytesRead);
        let offset = 0;
    
        for (const chunk of chunks) {
          result.set(chunk, offset);
          offset += chunk.length;
        }
    
        let str = (new TextDecoder().decode(result));
        // stuff to do with the str here
        return resolve(str);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error downloading the file:', error);
        reject();
      }
  });
}
```

but the React Native fetch api does not provide a ReadableStream so this does not work. Is there any way to do this in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I'll be using react-native-webview to use the web fetch function which allows me to use a ReadableStream, then once I get the bit of data I want I'll use window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage to pass it back to the RN app.